# AEM + React Integration for AEM versions of 6.1 and 6.2

Tags: reactjs, react-router, aem, cqrs

I'm looking for to integrarte AEM + react application. My Project uses 6.1 version of AEM-CQ. How do I integrate react without SPA. Can some one give steps guidance please?

Comment: Please provide more detailed, what you wanna reach? I'm afraid, that nobody can help you with this question.

Comment: As @AlexanderBerndt said, the most likely answer will be: create a clientlib for React and make sure, you get the data needed for the SPA, for example via servlets.

Answer (score 0):

I found these two links from adaptTo conference, hope they are useful to you.

A Non-SPA approach for AEM with React - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Sdt5Onh3zk
Using React to enable Web Developers to work with AEM - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Byfs7ptHhiU

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.